# SQL syntax error in irb with gem mysql2

Tags: mysql, sql, rubygems, mysql2

I am studying ruby in irb, the part about SQL.

i tried to query like

`db.query("ALTER TABLE people MODIFY (id integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY)")`

but irb gave me an error

> Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax

I googled it but still i think there is no problem in my query,
Is there any problem in query? or is it some kind of another problem?

Comment: Try removing the parentheses.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you, i removed parentheses inside quotes and it works. it was a simple problem. i'm so embarrassed :$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More information on the `ALTER` function syntax [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html).

```
ALTER TABLE people MODIFY id integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Comment: thank you. i had known it needs parentheses after part of MODIFY :$